# Unity 2018: UI button OnPointerDown not function as expected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am testing the function of UI Arrow Button which is supposed to translate a car object in x and z position in a 3D scene.

My target platform is WebGL. I coded both the control of keyboard arrow button for desktop and control of UI arrow button for both desktop and mobile.

The keyboard control worked fine in PC but the UI arrow button didn't work as expected both in desktop and mobile.

I logged the OnPointerDown() function which is in the script attached in the UI arrow button and the log didn't show up when the UI button was pressed down.

How to get the UI arrow button function when it is pressed down?

The Image of the Interface is here.
[image]

And my scripts are here:

the one attached to car object

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CarPlayerControl : MonoBehaviour {

public float speed = 40;
private bool touchCtrl = false;
private float xInput = 0f;
private float zInput = 0f;

void Awake(){
    //if (Input.touchSupported && Application.platform 
         //     != RuntimePlatform.WebGLPlayer){
        //touchCtrl = true;
        //}
        }

void FixedUpdate(){

    xInput = 0f;
    zInput = 0f;

    if (touchCtrl)
    {
        //if (Input.GetButton("ButtonUp"))
        //{
        //    xInput = 1.0f;
        //    Debug.Log("button up " + xInput);
        //}
        //else if (Input.GetButton("ButtonDown"))
        //{
        //    xInput = -1.0f;
        //    Debug.Log("button down " + xInput);
        //}
        //else if (Input.GetButton("ButtonLeft"))
        //{
        //    zInput = 1.0f;
        //    Debug.Log("button left " + zInput);
        //}
        //else if (Input.GetButton("ButtonRight"))
        //{
        //    zInput = -1.0f;
        //    Debug.Log("button right " + zInput);
        //}
    }
    else //mouse
    {
        xInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        zInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    }

    Move(xInput, zInput);
}

public void Move(float xInput, float zInput)
{
    float xMove = xInput * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    float zMove = zInput * speed * Time.deltaTime;

    float x = KeepXWithinRange(xMove);
    float y = transform.position.y;
    float z = KeepZWithinRange(zMove);

    transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, z);
}

private float KeepXWithinRange(float xMove){
    float x = transform.position.x + xMove;
    return Mathf.Clamp(x, 0, 900);
}

private float KeepZWithinRange(float zMove)
{
    float z = transform.position.z + zMove;
    return Mathf.Clamp(z, -470, 500);
}
}
```

and the one attached to the UI Up arrow button

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ButtonUpControl : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{
public GameObject car;
private CarPlayerControl carPlayerControl;
private bool mouseDown;
private float xInput;

void Awake()
{
    carPlayerControl = car.GetComponent<CarPlayerControl>();
    mouseDown = false;
}
void Start()
{

}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (mouseDown) {
        xInput = 1.0f;
    }
    else {
        xInput = 0f; 
    }

    carPlayerControl.Move(xInput, 0f);
}

public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    mouseDown = true;
    Debug.Log("on ptr down btn up ");
}

public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    mouseDown = false;
    Debug.Log("on ptr up btn up ");
}
}
```

Comment: Do you have an EventSystem in the scene? Does your camera have a `PhysicsRaycast` component or is the button on the UI layer? and is `ReceiveRaycast` in the Image component of your button enabled?

Comment: What about using a usual [Button](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Button.html) instead?

Comment: The button is in the UI Layer and there is no PhysicsRaycast component in the camera and no ReceiveRaycast in the image component. This UI button is supposed to enable user control in mobile. Isn't the usual button only for keyboard control in desktop?

Comment: ReceiveRaycast should be on. And no the Button is supposed to be a button. I'm not speaking of `Input.GetButton` but the `UI.Button` component

Comment: so if only the receive raycast is on,  it should function as expected with my code?

Comment: You could at least try it ;) but yeah it should I guess

Comment: set the image component as raycast target, right? I can't see the log in the OnPointerDown function when pressed it.